# Path not being searched in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, environment-variables

I am trying to add the Android Debug Bridge to my PATH in Win XP so that Eclipse won't complain about not being able to find it.

Even after I add the platform-tools directory to the path and reset the computer, adb is still not found by the command prompt.

My current path is:
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;C:\WINDOWS\system32
\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: If I remember right, path variables only specify the immediate folder to search in (that is, it won't search inside children folders on the path you specified). Are you sure you are pointing to the right folder?

Comment: Yes, adb.exe is in the platform-tools directory.

Answer (score 0):

Could [this is be the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375175/could-not-find-adb-exe-after-upgrade-to-android-sdk-2-3/4375439#4375439) that you're looking for?

**EDIT:**
Have you tried the other suggested solutions on that page as well? Many claim they were able to fix similar issues with not being able to locate adb.exe.

Comment: No. Again, adb is in the directory. Eclipse complains about not being able to find it, but the executable is in there. I will try updating the adt plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact message you receive when you type adb.exe at a command prompt?

I get:

'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(& rightfully so as I do not have adb.)

Does adb.exe need to be run as Administrator or anything like that?
A Path you may have set, may not be set for another user - if using something like, "Run As".

Comment: I'm the one who installed it and I am an admin. Yes, that's what I get in command prompt when I try it with that path.